# Failing to .click() on an element - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

Why cant the element be clicked at? It is the correct Xpath as far as I am concerned (got it from Firebug).

The task is simple, namely to press the blue settings button with a cogwheel.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.agar.io/")

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[11]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/button[1]').click()
```

***Error code:***

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
 locate element:
 {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[11]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/button[1]"}
```

The code worked a while ago before the website was slightly updated ( I have also updated the code with a new XPath) but I am not sure why it throws **NoSuchElementException** this time.

Comment: Chrome returns this xpath `'//*[@id="agario-main-buttons"]/div[1]/button[1]'`. Your code works when using this xpath.

Comment: What element you trying to click? Settings button?

Comment: That xpath is wrong. Upon initial load, the body doesn't contain eleven top-level divs.  Perhaps you're taking some action (such as hovering over the cogwheel) that creates additional divs on the fly?

Comment: @NickQ, yes, it is the blue one close to the play button.

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks, I will try it out in my code later.

Comment: @JohnGordon that might be the last thing you mentioned. That page is generally hard to automate since it has a lot of nested canvas elements. I will try to solve that problem and will be back with a solution if there are any.